# ERROR: Each dictionary in the list "icons" should contain a non-empty UTF8 string field "sizes"

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments

In my web app using `stripe`, inside the checkout page this error occurs. Is it something related to stripe bug? Anyone can explain this?

Comment: Could you share the screenshot with the full error message where you faced this?

Answer (score 5):

I am receiving the same error using Node.js w/ Express, as well as a similar error stating, "...string field 'type'". Upon looking at the error and combing over my own code for anything that could possibly create an error like this, I've come to the conclusion that I'm almost certain that this is a bug/issue on Stripe's end, not on the client's end.

I could definitely be wrong, but the error stems from Stripe's codebase, and doesn't seem to be affecting the way anything works--at least for test cases while running a test/dev key.

[image: This path leads to a Stripe file.]

[image: Here]

I would definitely contact Stripe if you have any issues--I will be inquiring about this myself, as there doesn't seem to be any other information regarding this (that I can find).

Comment: Did you contact Stripe and did you get any response? I also see these errors in my page. I'm assuming it's to do with the payment icons that stripe inserts into the Card Number box.

Comment: To be honest it's been so long I now I can't remember if I contacted them or if they responded, if I contacted them. However those errors (warnings) went away a few months ago.

Comment: I'm in a testing mode still, maybe it's related to that.
I get it just after payment in https://user-credits.dev/offers/monthly

Comment: It's definitely a possibility, it's still something I'd bring up to Stripe technical support though.